# WS2815 Erratic Color display

Tags: led-strip, led-driver, pixels

I have a two strips of WS2815 neopixel LED lights (400 pixels per string) being driven by WeMos D1 minis with the WLED library to control them.

Since the two strips are on opposite sides of my porch, I purchased a 25' 18/4 solid wire to run the strip furthest away from the control box & power. However, when turning the pixels on they turn the appropriate color for a second and then the entire line starts to flash erratic colors. It isn't flickering or dimming so much as changing color randomly. If I reduce the amount of LEDs being controlled to 200 or less it seems to function fine (other than only half the string being used).

My first guess would have been voltage drop, but that doesn't seem consistent with the result being produced (I would have expected discoloration or dimming). This is my second cable (the first one being 22/4, thinking the gauge was too small I went with 18 on the new one), the new cable seems to be able to control more lights than the prior cable but not the whole strip.

From individual testing I'm positive that the power supply, controllers and LED strips are all good and in working order, so I'm left thinking it has something to do with the length of the cable.

Am I overlooking something? Could 25' be too long for a data/neutral wire? Would splicing in a single pixel halfway through do any good (acting as a signal repeater)?

Comment: You might have interference due to the long 25ft wire for data. Try using a 25ft CAT5 ethernet cable instead for it. It's 24AWG, but less prone to interference. **Don't use it for the 12V supply though** These strips use a lot of wattage after all.

Comment: @NatsuKage Do you mean a single wire from the Cat5e cable (like solid blue for example) or twisting all of them together?

Comment: Use just a single twisted pair for each color. ex. DO = Blue / DI = Orange / BO = Green / BI = Brown ----Ground all the white wires.  If that doesn't help, use one pair each: DI = Blue / Do = Blue/White. Try using a cable which shield each individual pair. Connect the shield to the ground.